# jQueryMobile - up/down button for listview

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

In my page I need to put buttons for up/down items in a , my client don't accept the drag/drop process, they want to reorder of items happens by buttons.

It is possible ?
I look for samples but don't see any kind of this situation, in general, the samples talk about jQueryUI and drag/drop

Comment: Not a built in feature. You would need to add buttons and script their ability. Can you provide some example code?

Comment: @Twisty Something like this, a simple listview...

http://jsfiddle.net/MauriceG/mzJkq/
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an easy answer.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t1ruyg11/16/

Mobile Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/t1ruyg11/16/show/

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery mobile Listview with drag and drop</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" id="lst">
      <li data-role="list-divider">Manual Sort List</li>
      <li class="first">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"></span> List Item 1
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"></span> List Item 2
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"></span> List Item 3
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"></span> List Item 4</li>
      <li class="last">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"></span> List Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-listview li.ui-li-static {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.ui-listview li.ui-li-static span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.ui-listview li.ui-li-static span.up {
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  top: 5px;
}

.ui-listview li.ui-li-static span.down {
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  top: 30px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var elements = {
  up: $("<span>", {
    class: "ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n up"
  }),
  down: $("<span>", {
    class: "ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s down"
  })
};

function sortRefresh(list) {
  var id = list.attr("id");
  var $lst = $("#" + id);
  $lst.listview("refresh");
  $lst.find(".first .up").remove();
  $lst.find(".last .down").remove();
  $lst.find(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
}

function sortMakeListArray(list) {
  var itemArray = [];
  list.find(".ui-li:not(.ui-list-divider)").each(function(ind, el) {
    itemArray.push($(el).text().trim());
  });
  return itemArray;
}

function manualSort(elem, dir) {
  var $list = elem.parent();
  var prevLi = elem.prev();
  var nextLi = elem.next();
  var temp = elem.detach();
  if (dir == "up") {
    console.log("Moving Temp Up", prevLi);
    if (temp.hasClass("last")) {
      temp.removeClass("last");
      prevLi.addClass("last");
    }
    if (prevLi.hasClass("first")) {
      prevLi.removeClass("first");
      prevLi.append(elements.up.clone());
      temp.addClass("first");
    }
    prevLi.before(temp.prop("outerHTML"));
  }
  if (dir == "down") {
    console.log("Moving Temp Down", nextLi);
    if (temp.hasClass("first")) {
      temp.removeClass("first");
      nextLi.addClass("first");
    }
    if (nextLi.hasClass("last")) {
      nextLi.removeClass("last");
      nextLi.append(elements.down.clone());
      temp.addClass("last");
    }
    nextLi.after(temp.prop("outerHTML"));
  }
  sortRefresh($list);
}

$(function() {
  $("#lst .ui-icon").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
  });
  $("#lst").on("click", ".ui-icon", function(e) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var $li = $t.parent();
    console.log("Clicked", $t);
    if ($li.hasClass("first")) {
      elements.up.clone().appendTo($li);
    }
    if ($li.hasClass(".last")) {
      elements.down.clone().appendTo($li);
    }
    if ($t.hasClass("up")) {
      manualSort($li, "up");
    }
    if ($t.hasClass("down")) {
      manualSort($li, "down");
    }
  });
  sortRefresh($("#lst"));
});
```

Basically, we add the buttons. Since this is being designed for Mobile UI, I tried to make the buttons as big as possible to make them easier to tap. We will detach the list item and will move it `up` or `down` based on which button was tapped. Conditionally, if it's the first or last item, we add or remove buttons from the list items.

**Update**

If you want to sort via bump, without buttons, but by determining if there was a tap on the top half or bottom half of the item, you can do this:

```js
function sortRefresh(list) {
  console.log("List Refresh");
  list.listview("refresh");
}

function manualSort(elem, dir) {
  var $list = elem.parent();
  var $prevLi = elem.prev();
  var $nextLi = elem.next();
  var $temp = elem.detach();
  if (dir == "up") {
    $prevLi.before($temp);
  }
  if (dir == "down") {
    $nextLi.after($temp);
  }
  sortRefresh($list);
}

$(function() {
  $("#lst").disableSelection();
  $("#lst").on("click", ".ui-li-static", function(e) {
    var $li = $(this);
    console.log($li.text() + " clicked");
    var posY = (e.offsetY !== null) ? e.offsetY : e.originalEvent.layerY;
    var mid = $li.outerHeight(true) / 2;
    console.log(posY + "/" + mid);
    if (posY < mid) {
      if ($li.hasClass("ui-first-child")) {
        return false;
      }
      console.log("Move " + $li.text() + " Up");
      manualSort($li, "up");
    } else if (posY > mid) {
      if ($li.hasClass("ui-last-child")) {
        return false;
      }
      console.log("Move " + $li.text() + " Down");
      manualSort($li, "down");
    }
  });

  $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var pageY = event.pageY;
    var offsetY = (event.offsetY !== null) ? event.offsetY : event.originalEvent.layerY;
    $(".report").text("pageY: " + pageY + ", offsetY: " + offsetY);
  });
});
```

```css
.report {
  font-size: 65%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery mobile Listview with drag and drop</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" id="lst">
      <li data-role="list-divider">Manual Sort List</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 2</li>
      <li>List Item 3</li>
      <li>List Item 4</li>
      <li>List Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="report">
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/oh1kon0u/6/

Mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/oh1kon0u/6/show/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and for your effort, I see the demos, as you told not is easy to implement it, but you create major part  of the code.